# Scripting access to a website using different ips

Tags: bash, wget, web-testing

I would like to test automatically my website from different locations in order to localize content's presentation. I think I have to write a bash script to access the website with wget program, using an ip from a list. There is somewhere an established solution to this kind of problem ?

Comment: Search for IP spoofing, or try anonymous proxy servers...

Comment: Wait, so if I'm from, say, Argentina, and I fly to, say, France, I will get stuff served in French? You can pick any two locations with different localisation options. It doesn't seem good - what if a German lives in Italy but still has "German" in his localisation preferences? You should be basing the localisation on that instead of the IP which is really unreliable to begin with. And using the locale the user has set is (I can't believe I'd have to write that) is the proper way to give them the locale specific information. Moreover, it's easier to test.

Comment: @Vld Your point is truly valid but it is weak compared to my client main requirement - ip-based personalization :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many solutions. I think to these ones :

1. IP spoofing. But it's not easy. In particular if you want orchestrate these tests to automate them...
2. Another solution is to use a reverse-proxy. An example: your application is hosted by Tomcat and you use Apache as reverse proxy. In this case you can easily configure several end-points in Apache where you lie about [XFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)
3. Another solution, you can rent VM in the cloud. This is a good approach if you want to perform real performance tests from a remote client, or check the behavior of Internet cache...
4. Some compagnies sells services to check availability of your web-stuff from different sites.